# How do you pick up the water balloons in Skylanders Swap Force Wii chapter 14?

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

We have the Wii (not U) version of Skylanders Swap Force.  We can't get past the fire fighting with water balloons section of chapter 14.  How do you pick up and carry the water balloons?  The youtube videos I've seen they just walk over to the pump and touch the balloon, but when we try this the balloon immediately flies away as if thrown.  We can't carry them to where the fires are.

This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the wii version also, and although there seems to be a few bugs with the wii version, this is not one that I know.  I have completed the story mode fine with no real issues at all.  The balloons you just walk up to and the skylander collects them.  To put the fires out you need to flick the wii control to throw the balloons.  If you are saying the balloons just fly away when collected as if thrown, I would suspect you are either moving the wii control too hastily or your control is perhaps faulty.  Make sure the main wii control is fairly still whilst using the direction on the nunchuck to move round and collect the balloons.   If you are sure you are doing this, then perhaps try a different control.  I would always recommend a proper nintendo one, as other cheaper versions do tend to do odd things like this sometimes.

Comment: It was the controller.  I swapped to a different one and was able to actually hold the water ballons.